# Dalvik debugging expressed via live machine:

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

DDMS in the Android Eclipse plug-in used to have a Run menu that looked exactly like the Java window Run menu, with a "Run Configurations..." that took the user to the exact same launch tabs used to start an app under development.

I liked using it through the DDMS because--once an under dev. app was originally installed on a handset--I could rewite that application and test it immediately on the same live handset simply by launching the app through the DDMS.  When the run was finished, that APK had in the process been updated directly on the handset--without me ever having to first remove the app from the hardware and reinstall the new version.

Something seems to have changed in the newest Android plug-in from last September (or later).  The DDMS-side Run menu no longer looks like the Java-side Run menu.  Instead the DDMS Run now has something called "External Tools," with a "Run As" and and "External Tools Configurations..." inside of it, neither of which allows me anymore to select my hardware Device in the upper left pane of the DDMS and Run it directly through there using the stuff I'd just written in the Java window.

Is there no way to do that now?

Comment: Okay, I got this running as before.  It was either (or all) loading a .java file into the DDMS File Explorer, and setting a radio button in a window within External Tools Configurations to something along the lines of the active project, and setting my handset to sync instead of just charging mode (which I thought I'd done before but maybe hadn't).

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me for a long time too.  It seems that if you have a java file open in your Java perspective and then switch to DDMS perspective than that run menu will be available.  If you have e.g. an XML file open before switching to DDMS then the menu isn't there.